# what is the difference between node and jspm and can node and jspm used together in a project

Tags: node.js, bundling-and-minification, jspm

I am new to web development using node and jspm.

Please explain the difference between node and jspm and how they can be combined used in a project.

Do we need to copy all our node dependency or node module folder to the production server?

Answer (score 0):

JSPM is the command line tool, that works in Node. Usin JSPM you can:

1. Configure your SystemJS config file to load all dependecies one-by-one in development
2. Build all dependecies into single minified js bundle for production.

So, you do not need to copy node_modules into production, just run [jspm bundle](https://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/bundling.html) command and copy it's output to production only.